# How to implement Lock Screen for Lollipop?

Tags: android, locking, android-5.0-lollipop, lockscreen

I could not find a good solution for the question. Some of them say using flags you can achieve it. But I think it is too old and it will not work for Lolipop.
I have a project on my University Last Semester and I am hard working on that, I have implemented all of the other features but failed for this.

Answer (score 2):

There are no lock screen APIs for Lollipop - the only APIs for displaying things on the lock screen for Lollipop and higher devices is through notifications.

Comment: Is it available for kitkat ?? if yes please share it .

Comment: That seems like a totally different question.

Comment: so ?? cant you tell me right here ? Iam too tensed on my project, please help me